# Email form content using PHP without loading a new page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I'm creating a form which sends me an email, but doesn't load a new page, instead it simply modifies some HTML and CSS values on that same page.

I've tried to implement it, and it's close to being complete, it just doesn't work correctly. Upon clicking submit, it doesn't validate the form, it loads the PHP page and says "Thank you...", then I get an email. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me understand and debug this. Thanks!

I can confirm that jQuery is linked correctly. I have the setup in this order:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script> (link for jquery)
 <style>
 <script>
   validateForm() JavaScript
   jQuery
<body> (no loading functions via onload)
```

HTML form:

```
<form  id='form' method='post' action='sendemail.php'>
                    Name: <br />
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
                    <br /><br />
                    Email: <br />
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
                    <br /><br />
                    Subject: <br />
                    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
                    <br /><br />

                    Comments: <br />
                    <textarea id="comments" name="comments" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
                    <br /><br />

                    <input type="image" src="..." name="myFormSubmitted" value="Submit" />        
                </form>
                <div id="formResponse"></div>
```

PHP - sendmail.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['myFormSubmitted'])) {
    $message = '';

    // Construct the message
    $message .= <<<TEXT
        Name: {$_POST['name']}
        Email: {$_POST['email']}
    Subject: {$_POST['subject']}
    Comments: {$_POST['comments']}  
        {$checkString}
TEXT;

    $to = 'sendMeHere@example.com';
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $from = $_POST['name'];
    $fromEmail = $_POST['email'];

    $header = 'From: ' . $from . '<' . $fromEmail . '>';

    // Send the email
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

    echo 'Thank you for your Email. We will get in touch with you very soon.';
}
?>
```

jQuery:

```
//On form submit, call validateForm, then post to PHP if validated
            $("#form").submit(function(e) {
                if (validateForm()) {
                    $.post( 
                        'sendemail.php', 
                        {
                            name: $('#name').val(), 
                            email: $('#email').val(), 
                            comments: $('#comments').val(), 
                            myFormSubmitted: 'yes'
                        }, 
                        function(data) {
                            $("#formResponse").html(data).fadeIn('100'); //Place echo in div
                            //Modify HTML & CSS here
                            $('#name, #email, #comments').val(''); //Clear the inputs - I don't understand this line
                        }, 
                        'text'
                    );
                }

                //Prevent event from bubbling
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                return false;
            });
```

JavaScript validate function:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            function validateForm() {
                var validName = false;
                var validEmail = false;
                var validSubject = false;
                var validComments = false;

                //Perform validation here...

if (validName && validEmail && validSubject && validComments) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
});
```

Comment: is your jQuery code waiting for the document to be ready?

Comment: What does "just doesn't work correctly" mean? Are you getting any errors (PHP or JS)?

Comment: To answer your embedded question in the comment after $.post(): JQuery doesnt send the email but sends the data with an asyncronous (ajax) http post to the specified php script which in turn should be sending out your email...

Comment: PHP sends the email, jQuery is used to send the data to PHP without reloading the page

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain why it doesn't work. See my comment on Benjamin's reply. :)

Comment: Did you leave out part of your validate function ? Or else it should always validate false.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your javascript in a ready event handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your javascript here...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin! I added that. Now I still see the same behavior, which is this: I click submit, it doesn't validate the form, it loads the PHP page which states "Thank you...", and I get an email.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "action='sendemail.php'" attribute on your html form tag.

Comment: Shouldn't change a thing. Jquery sumbmit() function runs before

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution. You can submit trigger the form submission in click event of the input[type=image]. I haven't checked it but hope that works!

```
$('input[type=image]').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $('#form').submit();
 });
```